# C++ Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My copy of Visual Studio 2013 Professional has incorrect syntax highlighting for C++. As visible in the screenshot below, comments starting with `//` are not highlighted, but strings are highlighted as comments.

This is not visible in the image, but comments delimited by `/*` and `*/` are highlighted correctly.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Not sure if it is related, but I am running Server 2012 R2 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with VS2013 Update 1 RC:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812067/visual-c-2013-syntax-highlighting-broken-for-c-style-comments-after-installation-of-visual-studio-2013-update-1-rc

Apparently uninstalling this update fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the C++ IDE is classifying the comments and strings correctly but the colors are simply off.  Try changing the string and comment color to the value you expect them to be

- Tools -> Options
- Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Change the String and Comment colors to be the values you like

Comment: No, the IDE is not classifying the comments correctly; if I change the color for "Comment" in VS, it affects everything that is green in my screenshot.

Comment: @MingSlogar that seems unlikely.  If that is the case then something much deeper is wrong with your install.  Parsing of the comment values is quite possibly the easiest part of the IDE.  Hard to think that got wrong.  Have you tried repairing the installation or reseting the settnigs entirely?

Comment: @MingSlogar that's in a completely unrelated part of the code.  The C++, C# and XAML code bases are in different DLLs and components

Comment: As a side note, I had the same problem with VS 2010 Pro, but not 2012 Express/Ultimate or 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: @MingSlogar the exact same code for C++ IDE highlighting runs in both 2013 professional and ultimate.  Seems like this is much more likely to be settings or installation related

Comment: If that is the case, how would I reset the settings?

Comment: @MingSlogar try 'devenv /resetSettings'.  You will need to run that from a visual studio command prompt

Comment: The settings were reset, but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: @MingSlogar try deleteing the .sdf and .suo files

Comment: That is not the issue, since it happens for brand-new solutions.